# Error: more than one instance of overloaded function matches argument list

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
class A
{
public:
    virtual int fun( int a=0, float f = 5.4)=0;
};
class B: public A
{
public:
    int fun(int i = 0, float k= 5.4)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int fun(int i= 8, float k = 4.5, char c = 'g')
    {
        if(c != 'g')
            return fun(i,k);
        else
            return -1;
    }
};
int main()
{
    //fun();
    return 0;
}
```

This program is a replica of my project code. I am getting a compile-time error  when I call `fun(i,k)` in `fun(a,b,c)`. I understand why I am getting this compile error, but I can't find an alternative. Please suggest an alternative.

Comment: This looks like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? There's probably a better solution than overloading.

Comment: As a general advise, don't mix overloading with default values. Remove either and your solution will become obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `fun(i,k)` is ambiguous because it may means that you want to call `int fun(int i, float k)` or `int fun(int i, float k, char c)` with `c='g'`

You may change one of the functions name to solve your problem.

Another solution is merge them in one function

```
int fun(int i= 8, float k = 4.5, char c = 'g')
{
    if(c != 'g')
        //code of int fun(int i = 0, float k= 5.4)
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: thanks.. i know it is ambiguous, but if i want to call that method how can i do??

Comment: i cannot change the function names.. & i cannot change the signature of A::fun(), because there are other derived classes which will use the old signature.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Adding overloads in a subclass is not a good idea in general. (Your overload will never participate in polymorphism anyway, so there's no point in naming it the same as the function in the base class.)

Comment: @Humam Helfawi, i will put the code of fun(i,k) into another private function & call that function in both fun(). that resolves one problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

switch around the arguments, and get rid of one default value, otherwise you have to rename them.

```
int fun(int i = 0, float k= 5.4)
{
    return 0;
}
int fun(char c, int i= 8, float k = 4.5)
{
    if(c != 'g')
        return fun(i,k);
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You design suggests that B is to be used through a pointer/ref to `A` but the additional overload in `B` is not visible in `A`. You're not extending the base interface but the specific derived class interface.

In case you want to do it anyway:

If you want to call the first overload in case `c` is not provided, you don't need any overload because you can call `fun(i,k)` directly.

Since arguments having default values need to be at the end, you'll either want to have the char argument first

```
int fun(char c, int i= 8, float k = 4.5) { return c != 'g' ? fun(i,k) : -1; }
```

or you can use an overload with no default values:

```
int fun(int i, float k, char c) { return c != 'g' ? fun(i,k) : -1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual int fun(int = 0, float = 5.4f) = 0;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    int fun(int i = 8, float k = 4.5f) override // You may change default value here
                                                // but not recommended
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int fun(int i, float k, char c) // it is not an override
    {
        if(c != 'g')
            return fun(i, k);
        else
            return -1;
    }
};
```

so `B::foo` with 0, 1, 2 arguments use the override method, with 3 arguments, it uses the overload.

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/GtFtUw)

with cases like

```
B b;
A& a = b;

a.fun(); // fun(0, 5.4)
b.fun(); // fun(8, 4.5) // That part may surprise user
```